# Separate categories by ","

Tags: php, wordpress

When separating the categories, the "," appears in the last category. e.g
Category1, Category2,

I am using this function.

```
// MultiNetwork
function MultiNetwork() {
    global $post;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'networks');
    $count = 0;
    foreach ( $terms as $term ){
        if ($count <= 1) {  
            $firstTerm = $term;
            $term_link = get_category_link($firstTerm->term_id);    
            echo '<span class="network"><a href="' . $term_link . '" rel="tag">' . $firstTerm->name . '</a></span>',',';
            $count++;
        }
    }   
}
```

I would like it to stay
Category1, Category2

Intente usando explode e implode.

Comment: You can use a `for` loop. If the element in the loop is the last one, then ignore the ",".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case, simply only echo the "," if that is not the last item.

For example, remove `,','` and then add the following line:

```
if ($count < count($terms)) { echo "," ;}
```

So Change these two lines:

```
echo '<span class="network"><a href="' . $term_link . '" rel="tag">' . $firstTerm->name . '</a></span>',',';
$count++;
```

to

```
echo '<span class="network"><a href="' . $term_link . '" rel="tag">' . $firstTerm->name . '</a></span>';
$count++;

if ($count < count($terms)) { echo "," ;}
```

Comment: Keep adding at the end ","

Comment: I have slightly amended my answer, please try again . You may also refer to [this sandbox](https://onlinephp.io/c/4988e) , click "execute" to see the result -- surely no `,` at the end now

Answer (score 0):

You can you use below code to resolve ", " problem.

```
 $terms = get_terms([
  'taxonomy' => 'networks',
  'hide_empty' => false,
]);

$count = 0;
foreach ( $terms as $term ){
  if ($count <= 1) {  
     $cat[] = $term->name;
     $count++; 
  }
}   

$data = implode(', ', $cat);
```

I have tried this code for the same. please look for the screenshot I'm attaching below.

[Screen shot of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjOq1.png)

Comment: In all entries is using the same categories.